# Xamarin Android: Why authentication to azure active diretory is not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, dynamics-crm

Hello everyone my name is Taniguchi

I am trying to authenticate to azure active directory but the  code sintaxe is showing an error.

Authenticate interface:

```
public interface IAuthenticator
{
    Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string returnUri);
}
```

authenticator class:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Android.Dependency(typeof(App11.Authenticator))]
public class Authenticator : IAuthenticator
{
    public async Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string returnUri)
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Count() > 0)
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);
        var uri = new Uri(returnUri);

        var platformParams = new PlatformParameters((Activity)Android.Context);
        var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, uri, platformParams);
        return authResult;
    }
}
```

where i calling the authentification:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        Authenticate();
    }

    public async void Authenticate()
    {
        string Nome_Usuario = "taniguchi.sales@ax4b.com";
        string clientId = "2b121ed5-9fe6-4ddf-bdea-9bbe8cd37bd0";
        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/ax4b.com";
        string returnUri = "https://ax4bdev.crm2.dynamics.com";
        string graphResourceUri = "https://ax4bdev.crm2.dynamics.com";
        var auth = Xamarin.Android.DependencyService.Get<IAuthenticator>();
        var data = await auth.Authenticate(authority, graphResourceUri, clientId, returnUri);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationAgentContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

The Line:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Android.Dependency(typeof(App11.Authenticator))]
```

is showing the error: 
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'DependencyAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Android' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you added the reference for DependencyAttribute?

Comment: you mean DependencyService?

Comment: On nuget I ve installed dependency model and dependency and still show the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [assembly: Xamarin.Android.Dependency(typeof(App11.Authenticator))]

**DependencyService** is usually used in **Xamarin.Forms**,but now you are **Xamarin.Android** project.you dont need **IAuthenticator** and **Authenticator** class ,you could write the method in your activity directly like (I'm not sure your Authenticate method works，only for the error of Dependency):

```
private  async void Authenticate()
    {
        string Nome_Usuario = "taniguchi.sales@ax4b.com";
        string clientId = "2b121ed5-9fe6-4ddf-bdea-9bbe8cd37bd0";
        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/ax4b.com";
        string returnUri = "https://ax4bdev.crm2.dynamics.com";
        string graphResourceUri = "https://ax4bdev.crm2.dynamics.com";
        var data = await Authenticate(authority, graphResourceUri, clientId, returnUri);

    }

    private async Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string returnUri)
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Count() > 0)
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);
        var uri = new Uri(returnUri);

        var platformParams = new PlatformParameters(this);
        var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, uri, platformParams);
        return authResult;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @Leo Zhu, the code wont work because is made for xamarin forms

Comment: I would like to know if there is a native way to authenticate to azure

Comment: maybe you could refer to [Add authentication to your Xamarin.Android app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started-users)

Comment: I would like to take it back what i said your code works for authentication in azure, @Leo Zhu thanks so much